# How to check Duplicate url on real time basis

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am creating an online directory website which has an form which user fills with the information about his/her website which will be approved after a thorough check. My problem is that I only want to add domain name (No sub pages/sub folder), so I'm using a stripping function for it, but the problem comes when I want to cross-check the user input ($_REQUEST['url']) url for duplicacy and return a value in real time that it already exist or not.

Stripping Code is

```
$input = 'http://www.google.co.uk/';
$input = trim($input, '/');
if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
    $input = 'http://' . $input;
}
$urlParts = parse_url($input);
if(isset($urlParts['path']))
{echo "We only accept domain name not sub pages.<br />";} else {echo "All is well.";}
$domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);
$domain;
```

and the ajax I'm using is

```
function checkUrl()
{var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("urlError").innerHTML=x.responseText;
    }
}
x.open("GET", "http://localhost/directory/canvas/check_link.php?url="+document.getElementById("url").value);
x.send();
}
```

and this is the php part

```
if(isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url']!="")
{
    $query="Select * from links where website='".$_GET['url']."'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
        echo "Url / Website already exist.";
}
}
```

I'm still a beginner and there may be something I have missed, I'll be glad if you can help me in any way.

Comment: For starters don't write the $_GET variable right into your sql statement like that.

Comment: You should work with error- / success-codes, and possibly return those as `JSON` object. That will allow you to check if the code returned is a succes-code, or an error-code, and let the `JavaScript` code decide to `return false` and stop the process or `return true` and finish the submission.

Comment: run the stripping code on the input before making the db query